# p3d.in embedding?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Should we have [p3d.in](http://p3d.in) embedding? It could be handy for [geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) or [modeling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling) questions.

Comment: Is it possible here?

Comment: could come in handy, but then those discussions become dependant on p3d. At the same time we want to avoid using video as answer, how is that different?

Comment: As one of the p3d.in developers I can say that we certainly wouldn't mind embeds being used here :)

Comment: @iKlsR well Math.SE and mathoverflow have MathJaX which is considered a "very heavy dependency" by Atwood; as far as I know p3d.in is fairly light. As a developer it doesn't strike me as being too difficult to implement (although it's easy for me to say...)

Comment: Indeed. It should be enough to implement a tag that takes a shortid. Upon rendering of the tag it would be replaced by an iframe.

Answer (score 5):

I can see how it could be useful, but in general I would have to say no, we should not enable it.

I feel that having this tool could potentially encourage more tutorial-style answers, which we should generally try to discourage. Most questions and answers on this site should be simple enough to be answered with text and screenshots.

Comment: Good point. We **don't** want tutorial-style answers.

Comment: I agree we shouldn't allow 3D embedding. I can't imagine many scenarios where an embedded 3d model helps illustrate a point.

Comment: Same here, it's bad enough we should even accept `.blends` at times. This is not a forum per say, answers should be concise and compact. I can only imagine this would clutter the site and encourage showcasing.

Answer (score 4):

I think we should, because we already need screenshots to answer many of the questions. Why not have screenshots in 3D? Also, it will end up saving space where multiple screenshots are required.

If tutorial requests are too prevalent, maybe just enable p3D in the answers? That would allow people to answer questions (specifically topology questions) with a 3D model.

Comment: I agree it would be helpful to have it available for answers sometime. I don't see how it would result in "tutorial style" answers, since you can't animate P3D embeds or anything.

Comment: That might work!